# Why the validation based on the capacity of the registration type is not working?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a select menu for the user to select the quantity for each registration type of the conference:

```
@foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
<li>
    <div>
        <span>{{$rtype->name}}</span>
    </div>
    @if(min($rtype->max_participants, ($rtype->capacity - $rtype->participants->count())) == 0)
        Out of capacity
    @else
        <select
                id="rtype_{{ $rtype->id }}"
                data-price="{{ $rtype->price }}"
                name="rtypes[{{ $rtype->name }}]">
            <option value="0">0</option>

            @for ($i = $rtype->min_participants; $i <= min($rtype->max_participants, ($rtype->capacity - $rtype->participants->count())); $i++)
                <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
            @endfor
        </select>
    @endif
    <span>X {{$rtype->presentPrice()}}
        €</span>
</li>
@endforeach
```

And I want to validate the quantity introduced by the user in the select menu.

I already have a custom `RegistrationTypeQuantity` rule that returns false if:

- the user didnt select no quantity for none registration type and click "Next"
- the user didnt select a value between the min_participants and max_participants columns of the registration type and click "Next"

Otherwise, it passes.

RegistrationQuantity custom rule:

```
  public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $count = array_sum($value);
        if($count == 0){
            return false;
        }
        foreach($value as $key=>$v) {
            $rtype = RegistrationType::where('name',$key)->first();
            if ( !$rtype ){
                return false;
            }
            if ( $v != 0 && ($v < $rtype->min_participants || $v > $rtype->max_participants) ){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

---

So this is working fine.

**Doubt:**

But is also necessary to validate the quantity introduced by the user considering the capacity column of the registration type. Each registration type has a capacity.

So, for example, if registration type "general" has capacity 10 and there are already 10 participants registered in the registration type "general". If the user introduce the quantity "10" for the registration type "general" and click Next it should result in a validation error.

Also, if registration type "general" has capacity 10, min_participants 1, and max participants 3 in the database and there are 8 participants registered in the registration type "general", in the select menu only appears 1 and 2. So, if the user introduces for example the value "3" for the quantity and click "Next" it should show a validation error, because the user should only be allowed to select quantity 1 or 2 because, 8 participants + 3 = 11 and the total capacity is 10. So the validation should fail.

But adding the code below to the `passes()` method of the `RegistrationTypeQuantity` rule is not working to achieve this validation:

```
if ($v <= min($rtype->max_participants) 
&& ($rtype->capacity - $rtype->participants->count())){
    return false;
}
```

Do you know how to also properly validate the introduced quantity considering the capacity of the registration type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    if(array_sum($value) < 1){
        return false;
    }

    foreach($value as $key=>$v) {
        if ( $v != 0) {
            $rtype = RegistrationType::where('name',$key)->withCount('participants')->first();

            if ( !$rtype ){
                return false;
            }

            if ($v < $rtype->min_participants || $v > $rtype->max_participants || (($rtype->capacity - $rtype->participants_count) < $v) ){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This validation rule will pass- **only if the selected quantity is** :

Between `min_participants` and `max_participants` &
 Less than the (capacity - current participants)

**Optional:**

Your validation rule will make `n` number of queries where you can reduce it to one. where `n` is the number of registration types selected by user.

**View**

```
@foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
    <li>
        <div>
            <span>{{$rtype->name}}</span>
        </div>
        @if(min($rtype->max_participants, ($rtype->capacity - $rtype->participants->count())) == 0)
            Out of capacity
        @else
            <select id="rtype_{{ $rtype->id }}" data-price="{{ $rtype->price }}" name="rtypes[{{ $rtype->id }}]">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                @for ($i = $rtype->min_participants; $i <= min($rtype->max_participants, ($rtype->capacity - $rtype->participants->count())); $i++)
                    <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
                @endfor
            </select>
        @endif
        <span>X {{$rtype->presentPrice()}} €</span>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Note that the `name` attribute of the quantity select changed. [Index changed from `$rtype->name` to `$rtype->id`.

**Validation Rule**

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    if(array_sum($value) < 1){
        return false;
    }

    $rTypes = RegistrationType::withCount('participants')->whereIn('id',array_keys($value))->get();

    foreach($rTypes as $rType) {
        if ( $value[$rType->id] != 0) {
            if ($value[$rType->id] < $rtype->min_participants || $value[$rType->id] > $rtype->max_participants || (($rtype->capacity - $rtype->participants_count) < $value[$rType->id]) ){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that `whereIn` used for accessing all required records in single query. Array of `id`s accessed using `array_keys` method on the quantity array.

Please let me know if any issue faced as I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks but like that if the user introduce a valid quantity and click "Next" is redirected to the registration page "https://proj.test/conference/1/conf-test/registration" and appears "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." instead of appear the registration page.

Comment: @John You have problem with the optional part?